# How to add padding on form segments in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, listview, uikit, swiftui, ios13

In iOS 13, some native Apple apps use a list style I am struggling to recreate. It's basically a `List` within a `Form` containing `Section`s and some entries.

The only difference is that each `Section` has padding to the left and right side and a corner radius around the edges.

Here is an example from the Home app of what I would like to achieve (also used in the Timer tab in the Clock app):

[image: iOS 13 Home app]

Applying the `.padding()`-Modifier to the `Form` doesn't work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      Form {
         Section {
            Text("foo")
            Text("bar")
         }
         Section {
            Text("foo")
         }
         Section {
            Text("bar")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am wondering if it is at all possible in SwiftUI or if this is just some UIKit-adjustment on a `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is new `UITableView.Style` called `.insetGrouped`. This is [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/insetgrouped?changes=_9)

You can set it with code:

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: frame, style: .insetGrouped)
```

Or with Interface builder:

[image: Ki]

SwiftUI **doesn't have this style (yet)**, but in the future, it should be a `ListStyle` that you can use with `.listStyle` modifier on a list. Currently available styles are:

```
.listStyle(DefaultListStyle()) // wich is PlainListStyle
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
// .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle()) // unresolved (yet)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with this modification to `Form` or `List`:

```
Form {
  Text("Hey")
}
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
.environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
```